# Reboot EC2 Amazon Linux (Redhat-based) from script

Tags: sudo, reboot, redhat-enterprise-linux

I would like to reboot my Linux from a Script.  The script does not run as root.

Using `sudo reboot` produces

> sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo.

A plain `reboot` gives the error

> Need to be root

I know I can edit my *sudoers* file, but is there an easier way?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to run the script not as root? Because if you launch the script with `sudo /bin/bash myscript.sh` it will run as root.

Comment: @Hastur How could I run as root? If that is possible that might work.

Comment: The command `sudo /bin/bash` for example launch a bash shell as a root. From that point ahead you are root. __It's better(==safer) to avoid it and to set up the sudo permissions limited to a single script and a related user__. To run the script as root you can do `sudo /bin/bash myscript.sh`. But, did I just said to you? __It's better to set the sudo privilege for the reboot one line script__. A script can usually fail in more ways you can imagine. So It's better than when it will fail it will do not as root :-) Imagine a failed path that becomes `DelDir=/` and a `rm  -rf ${DelDir}/*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon provides a library for all of these type of functions, so that they can be performed at the EC2 level, without resorting to bad ideas within the virtual machine itself.

You can use [`ec2-reboot-instances instance_id`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-RebootInstances.html) to request EC2 to reboot any instance, including itself. An instance can fetch its own ID using either:

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

or

```
ec2-metadata -i
```

so as a one-liner on the command line, you would use this:

```
ec2-reboot-instances -O YOURAWSKEY -W YOURAWSSECRET --region=YOURREGION $(ec2-metadata -i |cut -d':' -f 2)
```

The full list of EC2 function is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/command-reference.html).

Comment: Thanks! That works for me. For those who read this : Note that, even after you have the instanceid, you have to specify or configure region and credentials.

So, your command line will look like

ec2-reboot-instances -O YOURAWSKEY  -W YOURAWSSECRET --region=us-west-2 $(ec2-metadata -i |cut -d':' -f 2)

Comment: @Joshua Fox good detective work. I forgot about that, I seem to recall I had [credentials and region set as environment variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-environment), but I haven't had any EC2 instances up and running to play with for some time. I need to include your comment in my answer to make it complete and provide a one-liner, but I ought to test it live first.

Comment: I loaded up an ec2 instance and I can't get the environment variable method to work, so I am going to simply copy your command line into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `reboot` , `halt` and `shutdown` commands usually require root for security reasons [[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361988/why-do-we-need-to-be-root-in-terminal-for-shutdown-and-restart)].
Writing on google `how to run sudo in a script` it answers with

> Add your script to the /etc/sudoers file with the NOPASSWD attribute, so that it is permitted to run without prompting for a password. You can tie this down to a specific user (or set of users), or allow it to be run with sudo by anyone on your system.

Fair enough if you can **limit the above to a one line script that launches only the `reboot` command**. This however will expose your computer to be rebooted without password from that *script+user* configuration.

The alternative it will expose you to the risk that everyone will have the possibility to restart your machine. Read the answers [[2](https://askubuntu.com/a/362015/196535),[4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166818/66388),[5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166851/66388)] for example

> ... you need to **add the suid-Bit** [[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid),[4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166818/66388),[5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166851/66388)] to those commands. But be aware, everyone on your system, that has access to the shell could then shutdown your machine.

But I'm convinced too that **to *use the suid* it is a Bad Idea**.
In the comment of [[2](https://askubuntu.com/a/362015/196535)] again it is suggested to modify with visudo...

```
%sudo ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
```

but at this point it's better to do **a one line script to reboot** for your user and to limit to that one only the reboot capability. (So you cannot reboot even as your user without password if not with that script).